# Symfony 4 remember me cookie

Tags: php, symfony, session-cookies, symfony4

I configured my Symfony 4 project with remember me. It is creating a REMEMBERME cookie with a expire date but once it's expired I'm not logged out.

**Security.yaml**

```
remember_me:
                name: REMEMBERME
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 120
                path:     /en/admin
                remember_me_parameter: remember_me
                always_remember_me: true
                token_provider: 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\RememberMe\DoctrineTokenProvider'
```

**Login twig**

```
<form action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post">
    <div class="block block-themed block-rounded block-shadow">
        <div class="block-header bg-gd-dusk">
            <h3 class="block-title">Please Sign In</h3>
            <div class="block-options">
                <button type="button" class="btn-block-option">
                    <i class="si si-wrench"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="username">{{ 'label.username'|trans }}</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="password">{{ 'label.password'|trans }}</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-sm-6 d-sm-flex align-items-center push">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-auto ml-0 mb-0">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" checked/>
                        <label for="remember_me">Keep me logged in</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-sm-right push">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.get('redirect_to') }}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'action.sign_in'|trans }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content bg-body-light">
            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <a class="link-effect text-muted mr-10 mb-5 d-inline-block" href="{{ path('user_signup') }}">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mr-5"></i> Create Account
                </a>
                <a class="link-effect text-muted mr-10 mb-5 d-inline-block" href="{{ path('forgot_password') }}">
                    <i class="fa fa-warning mr-5"></i> Forgot Password
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**AdminController**

```
public function index(PostRepository $posts): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

    $user = $this->getUser();
    return $this->render('admin/dashboard.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

**User Roles**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "ROLE_ADMIN"
  1 => "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"
]
```

What am I missing ? The REMEMBERME is removed automated, if I remove PHPSESSID I have to re-log. But should it not be working without removing the PHPSESSID manually ?

Comment: So you expect that a user is logged out automatically once the remember me cookie expires? I think that is not the purpose of the remember me cookie. This cookie can be used to gain access when there is no 'logged in' session available, not to log out active users with an active session when it expires.

Comment: Can you show the code of `User::getRoles()` method?

Comment: @Jeroen See https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/remember_me.html, "This means that when the session ends they will be logged out and have to provide their login details again next time they wish to access the application"

Comment: @BoShurik I'm using the Symfony UserInterface https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.php

Comment: @Noob Yes when their session ends, not when the remember me cookie expires right?

Comment: @Noob I want to be sure you did not return `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ` in your `getRoles()`

Comment: @Jeroen Ok, so I have to set the Session to auto log out of the user ? In Symfony this is not set with a expiry date

Comment: @BoShurik what do you mean? Could you elaborate

Comment: @Noob I mean you should not return `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` "role" from `User::getRoles()` method. You probably not doing so, but you did not show the code so I can only guess

Comment: @Noob By default, the session will expire when the user closes his browser if you want to change that you should take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime